# not able to pass string though intent android

Tags: android, android-intent

This is Andrj activity

```
 private void switchActivity(String key)
    {
        String r="123";
        Bundle basket=new Bundle();
        //basket.putString("key", key);
        basket.putString("roll", r);
        Intent i=new Intent(Andprj.this, extra.class);
        i.putExtras(basket);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

this is extra activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exam);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    setContentView(R.layout.exam);
    Bundle gotbasket=getIntent().getExtras();
    String gotbread=gotbasket.getString("roll");
    tv.setText(gotbread);
}
```

The display coming is TextView only...(default value)

Comment: Try to remove one the 2nd  `setContentView(R.layout.exam);` because you have two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.exam);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        Bundle gotbasket=getIntent().getExtras();
        String gotbread=gotbasket.getString("roll");
        tv.setText(gotbread);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to `invalidate()` your view after set text? **<-----not needed.**

Or you should call `setText()` before `setContentView()`. **<-----wrong**

**Update:** both lines above are incorrect. Sorry about it.

Comment: No! Calling `setText()` redraws the `View` as `invalidate()` would. Also, you can't call `setText()` on a `View` that hasn't been `inflated` yet through `setContentView()` or by using an `inflater`

Comment: You're welcome. That's how we learn :) I appreciate your edit but it would be better to delete the answer